# How to get CommonPrefixes from an Amazon S3 ListObjects Iterator

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, sdk, amazon-s3, phar

I'm trying to get a list of objects in a bucket into an organised list, with folders and files.

In the documentation, [S3 Listing Keys Hierarchically Using Prefix and Delimiter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingKeysHierarchy.html), Amazon states that when there are other directories in the currently selected directory:

> Amazon S3 groups these keys and return a single CommonPrefixes element

I have the following code:

```
$iterator = $client->getIterator(
    'ListObjects',
    array(
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Prefix' => $dir,
        'Delimiter' => '/'
    )
);
```

which does a good job. It gets all the objects in a bucket (unlike the low-level `ListObjects` method, which returns a max of 1000 objects) and displays them alphabetically.

If I tell this iterator to return an `array` like so:

```
$objects = $iterator->toArray();
```

I can then use this `array` in a `foreach` loop

```
foreach ($objects as $object) {
  echo $object['Key'] . "<br/>\n";
}
```

which gives me all the pointers to files:

- folder/subfolder/file.ext
- folder/subfolder/file2.ext
- folder/subfolder/file3.ext
- folder/subfolder/file4.ext
- folder/subfolder/file5.ext

It isn't showing the other directories in this directory though.

Calling `$iterator->get('CommonPrefixes')` returns `null`. Any other operations on the `$iterator` variable crash the code.

How can I get access to the full set of responses in the `ListBucketResult`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `getIterator()` method has a third parameter for options specific to the iterator object. The S3 ListObjects iterator is actually a concrete class and specifies some custom options in its docs: `return_prefixes`, `sort_results`, and `names_only` (see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.S3.Iterator.ListObjectsIterator.html). Use `return_prefixes` to get the `CommonPrefixes` intermingled with the objects. Try this:

```
$iterator = $client->getIterator(
    'ListObjects',
    array(
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Prefix' => $dir,
        'Delimiter' => '/'
    ),
    array(
        'return_prefixes' => true,
    ),
);

foreach ($iterator as $object) {
    if (isset($object['Prefix'])) {
        // For Common Prefixes
        echo $object['Prefix'] . "<br/>\n";
    } else {
        // For Objects
        echo $object['Key'] . "<br/>\n";
    }
}

// Also Licensed under version 2.0 of the Apache License.
```

Comment: This is why I don't like Amazon's 'documentation'. Does it work the same with `getListObjectsIterator`? 

In the link I mentioned there is a distinct difference between the `CommonPrefixes` array and the `Contents` array. Isn't there a way to only get the `CommonPrefixes` via `$iterator->get()` or something?

Comment: I'm sorry you don't like the docs, but this is kind of a weird edge case for iterators. If you have suggestions on how to improve the docs, please let us know in our issue tracker.
Yeah, `getIterator('OPERATION', [PARAMS], [ITERATOR_OPTS])` is the same as `get<OPERATION>Iterator([PARAMS], [ITERATOR_OPTS])`. If you want to deal with *only* `CommonPrefixes`, then you should just use the plain API. In general, iterators should only emit one type of thing. Since it is the "ListObjects" operation, the iterator emits S3 objects. Being able to get the CommonPrefixes as well is an extra feature.

Comment: You can ditch the iterator and do `$result = $client->listBuckets([/* ... */]); $prefixes = $result->get('CommonPrefixes');`, but if you have more than 1000 objects/prefixes, you have to make more requests with `'Marker'`s to get the rest.

Comment: That's why I wanted to use the `iterator`. So I don't have to do more requests. I also think this isn't an edge case. I just want to get all files and 'folders' and show them as actual navigation while the user makes their way through all the objects. I ended up using the normal `listObjects`, because it returns a `['CommonPrefixes']` and, as you mentioned, `get('CommonPrefixes')` which is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: If that's what you are doing, then I'm wondering why my code example above wasn't suitable for that use case. I'd like to chat with you more about this over email. I might have some more ideas for you or be able to help you optimize what you've already done. I'm on gmail with the username jeremeamia.

Comment: Is this method (return_prefixes) valid in v3 sdk? Using this method in v3, I still see only the keys and the prefixes are not returned.

Comment: It is not, but you will find that the "Paginators" feature in v3 is more flexible. Relevant examples are on this page in the V3 docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/guide/paginators.html

Comment: What is the use cases that 'CommonPrefixes' solves? I haven't understood the use cases for this yet.